# Why is the time complexity of this code O(n^2)?

Tags: python, time-complexity, runtime

```
def isPalindrome(str):
    reversedString = ''
    for i in range(len(str)-1,-1,-1):
        reversedString += str[i]
    return str == reversedString
```

Why is the time complexity of this code O(n^2)?
If it's wrong what is the time complexity of it?

Comment: [Shlemiel the Painter](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/). Also, `str` overwrites a builtin function.

Comment: Appending to a string is O(N) because it might require the contents of the string to be copied. You do that N times in a loop, it's O(N²)

Comment: Try "reversedString = str[::-1]"

Comment: Because every time you do `reversedString += str[i]` it costs O(N), which is the size of the resulting string. So, suppose the final length is N, you would have a total of 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N, i.e. the sum or an [arithmetic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum), in this case, we can use the formula n*(n + 1) / 2, which is going to be something like (1/2)*n**2 + (1/2)*n, which will be O(N**2)

Comment: Crap, that was supposed to be `n*(n + 1) / 2` -> `(1/2)*n**2 + (1/2)` -> `O(N**2)`

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is O(n^2) because of how you're building the reversed string 1 character at a time with the `+=` operation.

In Python, strings are immutable, so every time you're adding str[i] onto reversedString with `reversedString += str[i]`, you're not simply appending a character to the end of the existing string. Strings can't change, so you're really building a new string which is an exact copy of reversedString but with one more character on the end and re-assigning the reversedString variable to that newly created string.

Building a string copy is a linear operation in the length of characters in the string. So for example, if you're reversing the string 'foobar', the strings you build along the way and the number of operations required to create them are:

```
"r":      1 operation
"ra":     2 (copying "r", writing "a")
"rab":    3 (copying "ra", writing "b")
"rabo":   4 (copying "rab", writing "o")
"raboo":  5 (copying "rabo", writing "o")
"raboof": 6 (copying "raboo", writing "f")
```

You can then see that in total, reversing the 6 character string "foobar" to "raboof" took `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 21` operations, and that in general reversing an n character long string with your algorithm will take `1+2+3...+n` time. The sum of integers from 1 to n can be written in closed-form as:

[image]

This is why your algorithm is O(n^2) (applied to our n=6 example, we get the expected result: `21 = 1/2 * 6 * 7`).

You could improve the algorithm to O(n) time and O(n) space by building the string all at once: appending to a list (which is O(1) per character rather than the O(n) `+=` for strings) and then joining the list into a string at the end (in O(n)), or simply using str[::-1] to reverse the string (also O(n)). You could even achieve O(n) time and O(1) space by just walking two pointers, `i` starting from the first character and moving right, `j` starting from the last character and moving left, and checking that `str[i] == str[j]` until `i` and `j` cross.

Also, be careful about your parameter names. `str` is the built-in name for the string class in python, and you're overwriting it in your function. It might have been better to name your parameter `string` or `s`.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of that code *might* be O(n<sup>2</sup>).  It actually depends on your python implementation.

As many other responders have mentioned, if `reversedString += str[i]` actually copies the entire contents of `reversedString` into a new string every time, then this will take O(n<sup>2</sup>) time, because that's how many characters will end up being copied in total.

However, there are ways of implementing string `+=` that don't actually do that, and python implementers are motivated to optimize string `+=`, because it is idiomatic in Python.  On implementations of the language that optimize simple string concatenation in this way, your code is O(n).

CPython, the reference implementation of python, has this sort of optimization for +=, although they warn you not to rely on it in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which says:

> For example, do not rely on CPython's efficient implementation of
> in-place string concatenation for statements in the form a += b or a =
> a + b. This optimization is fragile even in CPython (it only works for
> some types) and isn't present at all in implementations that don't use
> refcounting. In performance sensitive parts of the library, the
> ''.join() form should be used instead. This will ensure that
> concatenation occurs in linear time across various implementations.

So, don't rely on it.  However this optimization is common enough that there's a good chance that your code is O(n) on whatever version of python you're using.